# kundera-cassandra criteriaquery with timestamp

Tags: java, cassandra, kundera

I want to create a Query with Kundera which compares a timestamp in the where clause. 
My cassandra model looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE booking.booking (
 id uuid,
 amount decimal,
 timestampCreate timestamp,
 timestampUpdate timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY (id, timestampCreate)
);
```

I have tried with following code (using javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder)

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(clazz);
Root<T> from = criteriaQuery.from(clazz);
from.alias("t");
criteriaQuery.select(from);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(from.get("timestampCreate"), (Date)myDate));
```

My property in the class:

```
@Column(name="timestampcreate")
private java.util.Date timestampCreate;
```

But when I execute I get following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
at com.impetus.kundera.property.accessor.DateAccessor.toString(DateAccessor.java:166) ~[kundera-core-3.2.jar:?]
```

I don't know from where the String comes from, I explicit give them a Date Object. Any suggestions?